# php and mysql use the date range can not show

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I had the question for the mysql date between select. In the mysql table, the field is varchar. The date range is '21-01-2013' and '31-01-2013', it can show the records, but the date range is '21-01-2013' and '20-02-2013', it cannot show the records.

```
"SELECT * from away_from_office where (awaydatefrom between '21-01-2013' and '31-01-2013') ";
```

Comment: the between operation, cant work on strings, as you mentioned; you need to convert the string to integer value, as shown by the JW user

Comment: The solution is to switch to a `DATE` field not `VARCHAR`. As answers show you can convert on the fly but that's more of a quickfix/patch than a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

you should convert it to date first using `STR_TO_DATE`, eg.

```
SELECT * 
from away_from_office 
where awaydatefrom between STR_TO_DATE('21-01-2013', '%d-%m-%Y') and  
                           STR_TO_DATE('31-01-2013', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

if the column has the same format with the one you've shown, convert it also

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(awaydatefrom, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN
```

if you have a chance to alter the table, or you're working with sample records, alter your table by changing the data type of the column to `DATE`.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the white check mark (*around 15mins to an hour later*). This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

Change column datatype to `DATE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html